# Setting up a listener for sql server alwayson availability groups without computer object rights in the AD

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, listener

Is there a way to create a sql server alwayson listener in an active directory (AD) environment where I don’t have create computer object rights? The AD admin created a computername for me. Is there a way to connect it to the Listener?
The following TSQL fails because I don’t have create objects rights in the AD.

`USE [master]
GO
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [VG-AdventureWorks2014]
ADD LISTENER N'DNSCOMPUTERNAME' (
WITH IP
((N'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', N'255.XXX.XXX.XX')
)
, PORT=1431);
GO`

Company policy does not allow AD rights for the DBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one proper way to pre-stage the listener and one way to allow the cluster to create the listener itself. Please note that YOUR account is not what is used to authorize to AD to create the listener when creating it through FCM/Powershell or SQL Server, the CNO is used as security context.

**The official pre-stage way**

1. Find the OU with the CNO in it
2. Create a computer object, name it your DNS listener name
3. Set the security on the new VCO and give the CNO full control over it (full isn't required but the list of needs is fairly long so just give it full control)
4. Create the listener through SSMS/TSQL/Powershell

**The official automatic creation way**

1. Give the CNO Create computer objects, list properties, read properties, write properties over the OU it resides in.
2. Create the listener through SSMS/TSQL/Powershell

They way that is listed in the other answer given is a mix of the pre-staging way with how to create multiple listeners. Additionally it has improper configuration when it comes to the security and will most likely come back to bite you if you do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround we found is as follows.

1. Setup AlwaysOn Availability Group (VG-AdventureWorks2014), skip listener creation in the wizard or T-SQL.
2. Go to cluster manager , create “client access point”.
3. Enter the computer name and static IP created by your network and active directory administrator.
4. The “client access point” (VG-AdventureWorks2014_Listener1) will appear offline and the IP will appear online. Now ask your active directory administrator to edit the “client access point” and change the status to online.
5. After both resources (client access point and IP) are online. Associate them with your availability group resource.
6. Now if you query: sys.availability_group_listeners on your sql server – you should see the listener
7. You still cannot use the listener. You need to go back to run T-SQL to assign port. I use 1433 (the default SQL listening port).

   `USE [master] 
    GO 
    ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [VG-AdventureWorks2014]
    MODIFY LISTENER 'VG-AdventureWorks2014_Listener1'
    (port = 1433)
    GO`
8. Now connecting to the listeners you created, it should bring you to the correct instance which host the availability group primary replica.

Ideas for this workaround came from a [Microsoft Blog by Qiang Wang](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlalwayson/2012/02/03/how-to-create-multiple-listeners-for-same-availability-group-goden-yao/).